# How forward slash "/" actually work in php?

Tags: php, include, slash

I confused about how forward slash work in php. Is it return the web root? Or computer files root? Or something else?

I tried several things, for example, my file structure in ubuntu server is like this:

```
/var/www/html/domainname.com/.
                          --/config/.
                             --/core.php
                          --/images/.
                          --/includes/.
                             --/footer.php
                             --/header.php
                             --/navigation.php
                          --/index.php
```

This is work (all of them included in `index.php`):

```
<img src="/images/logo.png" />    # in header.php
<a href="/">Home</a>              # in navigation.php
<a href="/test/test.php">test</a> # in index.php itself
```

This doesn't work:

```
<?php require_once('/config/core.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('/includes/header.php');?>
<?php include_once('/includes/navigation.php');?>
<?php include_once('/includes/footer.php');?>
```

Why the last four examples doesn't work? The "/" character should returns `domainname.com` right? Or it returns "/var/www/html/" instead?

My goal is to put all files that needed to be included in `includes` directory. So, every `.php` file can access them relatively even if the `.php` file stored in sub directory.

Comment: its relative to the current running script, just add a `..`

Comment: So, in `index.php` case, it wil return `/var/www/html/` like that?

Comment: no, just check your `include_path` settings, if you start with `/` it will start looking on that `include_path` setting. in your case its `../` to move one level back from where your script is running

Comment: @BagolDaplun `/` is always `/`. And `/` is root folder. For UNIX OS its... `/`! For Windows, it's usually `C:`, but sometimes apache will return your access folder. To be sure, always use relative paths.

Answer (score 2):

Now I understand. The forward slash `/` works differently in `.php` and `.html` documents.

in `.php` files, `/` means the root folder of computer, `/` in unix and `C:` in windows like Forien said in the comment. But, in `.html` files, `/` means the root folder of website or `/var/www/html/domainname.com/` in my case. That's why I confused lmho.

So, this code:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<img src="/images/logo.png" />
```

will look in `/var/www/html/domainname.com/` even though it's written in `.php` files. Because `.php` files send it to browsers as `.html` files. The same goes for this one:

```
<?php echo '<a href="/">Home</a>'; ?>
```

This one above still look in `/var/www/html/domainname.com/` because `.php` files echoed it as `.html` files to web browsers.

But, this will be different:

```
<?php require_once '/includes'; ?>
```

It will look in `/` in unix or `C:` in windows. Because `.php` files work in server computer. That's why the last one will not work. There's no `/includes` directory in server root directory. So, in order to make it works, I have to use this:

```
<?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes'; ?>
```

That's my conclusion if I'm correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the last four examples doesn't work? The "/" character should
>   returns domainname.com right?

Wrong. It literally searches for the path `/config/core.php`, `/includes/header.php`, etc.

Remove `/` from the beginning of the path or add `./`, then it will search from current working directory. You can use `./` and `../` for searching files relatively.

You can use/set PHP configuration `include_path` too.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

And also look logs for better understanding. :)

**UPDATE**:
Also check [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php), this might be helpful to you.

```
chdir('/var/www/html/domainname.com');
<?php require_once('./config/core.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('./includes/header.php');?>
<?php include_once('./includes/navigation.php');?>
<?php include_once('./includes/footer.php');?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log 

It is not set generally, so check apache logs.